# How to prevent from woocommerce css over rides template css file?

Tags: css, woocommerce, overriding

As you see in following picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BejH3.png).

woocomerce css styles has magically over ride my template css (after using yith tab manager permiume (disabling doesn't help).
You can see that disable those styles from woocomerce.css will prove that, y template style is still there.
How can I prevent from this issue ?
Here is the website link for that page
[amatistrading](http://amatistrading.ir/product/%DB%8C%D9%87-%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84-%D8%AF%DB%8C%DA%AF%D9%87/).

I used this code in functions.php of template but it didn't work:

```html
:// Disable WooCommerce's Default Stylesheets
function disable_woocommerce_default_css( $styles ) {

  // Disable the stylesheets below via unset():
  unset( $styles['woocommerce-general'] );  // Styling of buttons, dropdowns, etc.
  // unset( $styles['woocommerce-layout'] );        // Layout for columns, positioning.
  // unset( $styles['woocommerce-smallscreen'] );   // Responsive design for mobile devices.

  return $styles;
}
add_action('woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 'disable_woocommerce_default_css');
```

Comment: p.s: rename the woocommerce.css from plugin files, will work, but i still dont know how to prevent from download that css file.

Comment: CSS styles cascade, so rules can be overwritten by other rules that are more specific or are declared later. I don't fully understand your question though, can you rephrase? Do you want to not load the woocommerce.css file at all?

Comment: @helgatheviking exactly, because renaming that file resolved my problem, so i want to prevent from loading that file, i used the code that i add to main question,in functions.php but it didnt work

Comment: Ok, could you try switching `add_action` to `add_filter` ?

Comment: @helgatheviking thanks for replying, i couldn't use that code but i found a way to solve problem. ( i will put the right code if i find any),first we can delete that stylesheet content, or act like me: disable all plugins(every single plugin) try to replace woocommerce files with orginal, then re active plugins, this method worked for me, it seems changing woocommerce files made this problem.

Answer (score 0):

i couldnt use that code(in main comment) but i found a way to solve problem. ( i will put the right code if i find any),first we can delete that stylesheet content, or act like me: disable all plugins(every single plugin) try to replace woocommerce files with orginal, then re active plugins, this method worked for me, it seems changing woocommerce files made this problem.